# Doctrine: Get all children of a many-to-many relation

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I need a single DQL query that would return all `posts` for a given `tag`.

`posts` and `tags` have a many-to-many relation, s given a tag.slug I should be able to get all posts related to that tag, but how?

UPDATE:

I'm using Doctrine 2.1 with Symfony 2, my entities look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles__posts")
 */
class ArticlePost
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ArticleTag", inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles__posts_tags")
     */
    protected $tags;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles__tags")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="slug")
 */
class ArticleTag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ArticlePost", mappedBy="tags")
     */
    protected $posts;
}
```

Comment: what you need is an 'exists' query, but it's hard to say anything more specific without the details, e.g. doctrine version and the tables structures and associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to search with one tag, try this:

```
SELECT post FROM ArticlePost post
JOIN post.tags tag
WHERE tag.slug = {$tagSlug}
```

If you want to search by more than one tag, simply change the condition to:

```
... WHERE tag.slug IN ( {$slug1}, {$slug2}, ... {$slugN} )
```